# Spark job fails on java 9 NumberFormatException for input string ea

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, java-9

I have a sample spark job which I am successfully able to run on java 8 but when I run same program on java 9 it fails with `NumberFormatException`

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
conf.setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("java 9 example");
SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> ds = session.read().text("<xyz path>");
System.out.println(ds.count());
```

**Exception Details:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "ea"  at
>   java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:695)   at
>   java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:813)    at
>   scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:229)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:31)   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.warnDeprecatedVersions(SparkContext.scala:353)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:186)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
>     at com.ts.spark.session.TestApp.main(TestApp.java:18)

**Maven spark dependencies:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Java Details:**

> java version "9-ea" 
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+156) 
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+156, mixed mode)

Are there any additional steps that I need to follow to setup spark on java 9? Thanks!

Comment: What version of spark you are testing ?

Comment: Even if you fix that problem it's unlikely anything in Spark will work in Java 9...

Comment: What was your module-info for the project for the given sample? Inquiring for a possible issue that could be related or not to this.

Comment: I don't have any module info, I only switch from jdk8 to 9 and tried to run this code sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That Spark does not seem to support non-`Int` values in version numbers (at least for the supported JVMs), which does not happen for non-early access versions, here comes the `ea` String.
Once Java9 will be properly released, it will run probably correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Gabor. are there any workaround to resolve this issue?

Comment: I do not know of any. :( I would try fixing this problem and see whether it works with Java9 or not.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that the scala StringLike is being called to parse "ea" (a portion of "9-ea") as an integer. The JDK 9 build used is old, newer builds dropped "-ea" as the JDK 9 release candidate approached. So get the latest JDK 9 download (jdk-9+181) and also submit a bug to Spark to examine the code that parses the version string. A good reference for the version string  scheme is JEP 223 (http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/223).